# Creating a blog service or a persistent chat with Table Storage

Tags: azure-storage

I'm trying azure storage and can't come up with real life scenarios when I would use it. As far as I understand the only index Table Storage has is Partition Key and Row Key. I can't sort or query on other columns without doing a full *partition* scan, right?

If I would migrate my blog service from a traditional sql server or a richer nosql database like Mongo i would probably be alright, considering users don't blog that much in one year (I would partition all blog posts per user per year for example). Even if someone would hit around a thousand blog posts a year i would be OK to load them all metadata in memory. I could do smarter partitioning if this won't work well.

If I would migrate my persistent chat service to table storage how would I do that? Users post thousands of messages a day and query history pretty often from desktop clients, mobile devices, web site etc. I don't want to lose on this and only return 1 day history with paging (which can be slow as well).

Any ideas or patterns or what am I missing here?

btw I can always use different database, however considering Table Storage is so cheap I don't want to.

Answer (score 0):

PartitionKey and RowKey values are the only two indexed properties.  To work around the lack of secondary indexes, you can store multiple copies of each entity with each copy using a different RowKey value. For instance, one entity will have PartitionKey=DepartmentName and RowKey=EmployeeID, while the other entity will have PartitionKey=DepartmentName and RowKey=EmailAddress.  That will allow you to look up either by EmployeeID or emailAddress. Azure Storage Table Design Guide ( http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-table-design-guide/) has more detailed example and has all the information that you need to design a scalable and performant Tables.

We will need more information to answer your second question about how you would migrate contents of your chat service to table storage.  We need to understand the format and structure of the data that you currently store in your chat service.